# Display jstree in jquery using data from a simple java class

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jstree

I have a function which returns an ArrayList<>. I want to put it in a tree.
Here is my java class:

```
public class Root{
    private int id;
    private String text;
    private String key;
 }
```

and in my jsp file, I created a simple div :

```
<div id="rootDiv"></div>
```

then on button click, I want to show the tree

```
<button type="button"  onclick="loadDateAndCreateTree()">
```

this is the jsp function loadDateAndCreateTree:

```
function loadDateAndCreateTree() {
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            dataType : "json",
            url : "loadAndGetData.json.action",
            data : {
            },
            success : function(data) {
                    if (data.listObjects!= null) {
                        var lisjson = data.listObjects;

                        $(function() {
                                $('#rootDiv').jstree({
                                    'plugins' : [ "wholerow" ],
                                    'core' : {
                                        'data' : lisjson,
                                        'themes' : {
                                            'name' : 'proton',
                                            'responsive' : true
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        });
```

data.listObjects is a ArrayList of the class Root

Comment: please help? just simple use of tree to display

Comment: What's the structure of the `lisjson` object. jsTree expects the json in a certain format to be able to render the tree.